# Accessing a function from a module

Tags: python, class, definition

I cant figure out how to add my simple function to my main program file. why not ?

when i do this:

```
import print_text 

echothis("this is text")
exit()
```

cant understand why people think this is such a bad question.

this doesnt work either:

```
print_text.echothis("this is text")
```

same thing happens if i type any of the answers below.
including:

```
from print_text import echothis
```

I just get this error:

```
from: can't read /var/mail/print_text
./blah3.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"this is text"'
./blah3.py: line 3: `print_text.echothis("this is text")'
```

or a variant without the /var/mail line...

*this file is named print_text.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import random
import string
import threading
import sys

def echothis(txt):
    woo=txt
    stdout.write(woo)
```

Comment: Actually you should get an error saying that `echothis` is undefined. Your import should be `from print_text import echothis`

Comment: What materials are you using to learn python? It sounds like you should just get better learning materials.

Comment: I don't see where the thread object is being created. Perhaps what you're missing is to instantiate the `print_text` class and calling the `start` method for that object.

Comment: import is not an include

Comment: You're using bash not python I guess, this is not a python traceback but a bash one. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** You're actually not having a python issue but a bash one. You're running your python script as if it were bash (hence the 'from: can't read from'), did you put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the beginning of the file you're running (not `print_text.py`, the **other one**)? You could alternatively call it that way: `python myfile.py` and it should work.

When you import a module, it is namespaced, so if you want to use anything that is from that module, you need to call it using the proper namespace. Here, you would call you `echothis` function using `print_text.echothis`.

Alternatively, if you want to include `echothis` in your main namespace, you can use the `from print_text import echothis` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import print_text

print_text.echothis("this is a text")
```